# Php recursion of a tree of comments, with global variable

Tags: php, recursion

```
<?php
tree($Comments, 0, 0);
$var = -1;
function tree($Comments, $parent_id = 0, $level=0) {
  global $var;
     foreach($Comments as $Comment){
          if($Comment['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
               If ($level > $var) {$var++;} else {echo ($var-$level+1); $var=$level;};
               for ($i=$level; $i>0; $i--)
                echo "-";
               echo $Comment['text']."<br>";
               tree($Comments, $Comment['id'], $level+1);
          }
     }
}
?>
```

This is my recursive method of displaying the tree of comments(thread comments), 
the problem is I have to make, in that (if ($level > $var) statement get variable $var of how many (`</div>` for a bootstrap design) I should use for making the design for the comment threads. The problem is that I get first result 1, which supposedly  I shouldn't, the rest gets as It should have to.

**Edit 1, Example of data in database(to easy understand):**

```
id id_theme parent_id user text
16 14 0 DomainFlag This is 1!
17 14 16 DomainFlag This is 2!
18 14 16 DomainFlag This is 3!
20 14 17 DomainFlag This is 4!
21 14 17 DomainFlag This is 5!
22 14 21 DomainFlag This is 7!
23 14 22 DomainFlag This is 8!
24 14 18 DomainFlag This is 6!
25 14 0 DomainFlag This is 9!
26 14 25 DomainFlag This is 10!
27 14 25 DomainFlag This is 11!
```

**My table:**

```
id
parent_id
id_theme
user
text
upVotes
downVotes
```

**My idea is to make a threaded system of comments like(with $level which I get from the recursive function):**

```
   0
     1
      2
       3
      2
     1
     1
   0
     1
   0
```

So I get this result with that 1 at first no matter what, which I shouldn't( **1** This is 1!). The rest is working perfectly.

```
1This is 1!
-This is 2!
--This is 4!
1--This is 5!
---This is 7!
----This is 8!
4-This is 3!
--This is 6!
3This is 9!
-This is 10!
1-This is 11!
```

Why that 1 at the beginning appears? I heard that global scopes isn't good to implement, why? and what I should do to not use it?